# Create column that stores hierarchy as comma separated values

Tags: sql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a table which has two columns **UNIT**, **M_UNIT** as shown below:

```
+------+--------+
| UNIT | M_UNIT |
+------+--------+
|   10 |     12 |
|   15 |     19 |
|   12 |     16 |
|   13 |     15 |
|   19 |     14 |
|   14 |     11 |
+------+--------+
```

I want to create a column **H_TREE** which stores hierarchy as comma separated values after recursively searching through UNIT & M_UNIT such that H_TREE starts with UNIT and ends with the last possible M_UNIT as shown below:

```
+------+--------+----------------+
| UNIT | M_UNIT |     H_TREE     |
+------+--------+----------------+
|   10 |     12 | 10,12,16       |
|   15 |     19 | 15,19,14,11    |
|   12 |     16 | 12,16          |
|   13 |     15 | 13,15,19,14,11 |
|   19 |     14 | 19,14,11       |
|   14 |     11 | 14,11          |
+------+--------+----------------+
```

Apologies if I am not clear enough, let me know if something is confusing. Thanks.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tabs.  Please add the appropriate tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should produce what you want:

```
WITH data (unit, m_unit) AS (
    SELECT 10, 12 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 15, 19 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 16 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, 15 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 19, 14 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 14, 11 FROM dual)
SELECT
    unit,
    m_unit,
    unit || ',' || listagg(root_unit, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY depth) h_tree
FROM (
    SELECT
        id, unit, m_unit,
        LEVEL depth, CONNECT_BY_ROOT m_unit root_unit
    FROM
        (SELECT ROWNUM id, unit, m_unit FROM data) data
    CONNECT BY
        PRIOR unit = m_unit)
GROUP BY
    id,
    unit,
    m_unit
```

If the lines in your table are distinct the `id` column is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your response Husqvik, you have a great solution. I have edited the first row of H_TREE as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do it this way.  You should have a column called ParentID or something.  Then build the tree when needed.

This is an example (SQL Server) that wires it all together:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
WITH DirectReports (ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, DeptID, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, edh.DepartmentID, 
        0 AS Level
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
        ON e.EmployeeID = edh.BusinessEntityID AND edh.EndDate IS NULL
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, edh.DepartmentID,
        Level + 1
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
        ON e.EmployeeID = edh.BusinessEntityID AND edh.EndDate IS NULL
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON e.ManagerID = d.EmployeeID
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, DeptID, Level
FROM DirectReports
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department AS dp
    ON DirectReports.DeptID = dp.DepartmentID
WHERE dp.GroupName = N'Sales and Marketing' OR Level = 0;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH data (unit, m_unit) AS (
    SELECT unit, m_unit from TABLE)
SELECT
    unit,
    m_unit,
    unit || ',' || listagg(root_unit, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY depth)   h_tree
FROM (
SELECT
    id, unit, m_unit,
    LEVEL depth, CONNECT_BY_ROOT m_unit root_unit
FROM
    (SELECT ROWNUM id, unit, m_unit FROM data) data
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR unit = m_unit)
GROUP BY
    id,
    unit,
    m_unit
```

I went with Husqvik's answer and used a table which had 500 rows and it worked perfectly. Thanks everyone for your responses.